# Check if a phrase in a link is starting by numbers then a letter with beautifullsoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to detect if the webpage has some links **starting** by a number and then 2 words like this :

- 23 reasons to... => status is "ok"
- 5 pictures to... => status is "ok"
- 10 photos that... => status is "ok"
- This 10 pictures will  => status is None

To check a specific word (keyword) from a list (keywords):

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html5lib')
links=soup.findAll('a')
clean_links = [link.text for link in links if link.text]
status = None
for keyword in keywords:
    for link in clean_links:
        if keyword in link:
            status = "ok"
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your `clean_links` looks something like this:

```
clean_links = ['23 reasons to .. ', '5 pictures to .. ', '10 photos that .. ', 'This 10 pictures will ..']
```

Now we need to split each element in that list, then check if the first one is digit and remaining 2 are words. Strings have `.isdigit()` and `.isalpha()` methods, which will help you here:

```
status_list = []
for link in clean_links:
    # Getting only first 3 words separated by space
    if len(link.split()) > 2:
        first_three_words = link.split()[:3]
        # -> ['23', 'reasons', 'to'] ...

        if first_three_words[0].isdigit() and first_three_words[1].isalpha() and first_three_words[2].isalpha():
            status_list.append("ok")
            # status = "ok"
        else:
            status_list.append(None)
    else:
        status_list.append(None)
```

`status_list` would look like this afterwards:

```
print(status_list)
# -> ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', None]
```

Comment: for some clean_links, I have a "index out of range" error. I can't figure out why

Comment: @Mathieu perhaps some `clean_links` contain less than three words and when u try to get index 2 it raises that error. How would you want to deal with the links with less than 3 words? 1 number and 1 word is enough or what?

Comment: OK. if links are less than 3 words, then status is still "no"

Comment: @Mathieu edited answer, check if this resolves the issue

Answer (score 1):

use `.isdigit()`

```
if link[0].isdigit(): # get first character, strip() maybe required
  print('start with digit')
else:
  print('start with non digit/number')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to match that pattern:
`/^[0-9]+\W(\w+\W){2}/gm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this:

```
import re

reg_pattern = re.compile('^[0-9]+ [A-Z|a-z]+ [A-Z|a-z]+.*')    
clean_links = ["23 reasons to", "5 pictures to", "10 photos that", "This 10 pictures will", "2 3 n"]
for link in clean_links:
    if reg_pattern.findall(link):
        print("ok: " +  link)
```

Output:

```
ok: 23 reasons to
ok: 5 pictures to
ok: 10 photos that
```

Modify the pattern as your needs to match the digits in words if required.